# Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/sharp'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to run some NodeJS code using Sharp and i'm getting the following error:

```
    [root@localhost myapp-backend]# node server.js 

module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/sharp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/myapp-backend/node_modules/sharp/index.js:11:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/myapp-backend/server.js:277:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried to check your path?

Comment: Yep, i did a google search before i posted and verified that my PATH was set up correctly, if that is what you mean?

Comment: Were any errors reported when `npm install` was run?

Comment: i recently munged by PATH variable, and instantly started getting this on a bunch of different projects. I probably need to add /bin etc

Answer (score 18):

Turns out the Debian 8.x distribution I used did not include vips but I did not get an error message. Running

```
apt-get install libvips
```

followed by

```
npm install sharp
```

resolved the problem and sharp is finally installed and working.

Answer (score 11):

It's probably due to Sharp not getting installed. When I installed it via 
npm, there were no errors, but when I went into `node_modules/sharp`, three were no build files.

You can try to build it by doing
`node-gyp rebuild`

But, before that, make sure you have Vips installed - that's a lib that Sharp uses. On Mac you'd do
`brew install homebrew/science/vips --with-webp --with-graphicsmagick`

After you build the Sharp library, you should be good to go.

Comment: On windows and linux, sharp comes with a pre-built vips binary. Just do `npm install sharp` and everything ought to work. On OS X you need to install vips with brew first, as you say.

Comment: `libvips ` should be installed manually using `apt-get` on Debian and then `npm install sharp`

Answer (score 2):

Check if you don't have build folder on `node_modules/sharp`, then run:

```
npm i sharp
```

it will reinstall and builds sharp. (worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error in Lambda function for s3 image crop.

I installed the sharp module as below and I was able to crop images using Node.js 14.x version.

```
npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp
```

Please check `"node_modules/sharp/build/Release/"` folder for "sharp-linux-x64.node"

Answer (score 1):

In my case installing the sharp for specific target version of node.js works, I used below command, but before that remove your existing `node_modules` folder or remove `rm -rf node_modules/sharp`

```js
npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux --target=16x sharp
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was updating to the latest Node 13 instead of the Node 8 that apt-get provides by default. Answering just for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

For me there were 2 issues:

- libvips library missing
- node_modules were migrated from x86 mac to arm arch (M3) (thus binaries not executable)

```
brew install vips
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install --cpu=arm64 --os=darwin sharp
npm install
```